# iOS: Add UIProgressView inside uicollectionview to show upload percentage of uploading to firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm develop an iOS app that upload a list of images to firebase storage, I need to put a progress view inside each cell of uicollectionview (which show each image in datasource) to indicate percentage of uploading this image to firebase storage.

I try this code:

```
func Upload(imageView: UIImageView)
{
    // Data in memory
    var data = Data()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.pickedImage, 0.8)!

    // Create a root reference
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString

    // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    let imageRef = storageRef.child("images/\(imageName).jpg")

    // Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
    let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        guard let metadata = metadata else {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            return
        }
    }

    let observer = uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
        print("snapshot.progress",snapshot.progress) 
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
        let percentComplete = 100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
            / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)
        print("percentComplete",percentComplete)
        let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "la")
        imageView.sd_addActivityIndicator()
        imageView.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageRef, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
    }

    uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
       self.url = imageName
        print(imageName)
        print("success")
        imageView.sd_removeActivityIndicator()
    }
     uploadTask.observe(.failure) { snapshot in
        print("Failuer")
    }
}
```

and:

```
arrayOfImages?[(arrayOfImages?.count)! - 1]?.Upload(imageView: cell.workImage)
```

but I'm couldn't to get that because reuse of cell in UICollectionView, How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

1- Create a class and paste this code inside a function

2- Make progress property inside that class and regularly update it inside the progress completion and another property for the image

3- Create an instance array inside the class and init it with the image and start the upload

4- Inside `cellForRowAt` get the current progress value for every index , that's how you avoid cell reusing and uploading of image that be uploaded or currently uploading

//

It would be something like this

```
class Upload {

    var currentState:State = .none

    var progress:Float = 0

    var img:UIImage

    init(image:UIImage) {

        img = image


    }

    func start () {

        currentState = .uploading

        ///

        let observer = uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            self.progress = snapshot.progress
        }

        ///


         uploadTask.observe(.success) { snapshot in
            currentState = .uploaded
         }

        //

    }


}

enum State {

    case uploading,uploaded,none
}
```

//

```
var arr = [Upload]()

for i in 0..<numberOfImages {

    let img = UIImage(named: "\(i).png") // or get it anyWay

    let up = Upload(image: img)

    up.start() // start it in cellForRowAt if item state is none

    arr.append(up)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit, are you mean I must use arr[indexpath.row].sendTofire at cellForRowAt will work correctly?

Comment: no , make the upload out of cellForRowAt and only assign the progress value in it

Comment: or if you wan check the current state and start if it's none

Comment: Many thanks to your time, but how can I assign the progress value, it's need to reloadData to make effect to ui.

Comment: I write that:
 let observer = uploadTask.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            self.progress =  Float(100.0 * Double(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
                / Double(snapshot.progress!.totalUnitCount)) //Float(snapshot.progress!.completedUnitCount)
        } and in rowatindexpath:
cell.workImage.alpha = CGFloat((arr?[indexPath.row]?.progress)!)
but it's not work

Comment: alpha is supposed to be a value from 0.0 to 1.0 make sure to configure the percentag to be with aspect to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176506/discussion-between-ali-a-jalil-and-sh-khan).